# Round images with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, rounding

Can i create round images with asp.net? Please advise. My requirement is to upload any image and get a rounded version of that created bu asp.net. I am using .Net framework 3.5, visual studio .net 2008.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://forums.asp.net/p/942160/1130380.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing and image manipulation with GDI+ is straightforward as the other answers suggested.

But please note this is an unsupported path, as stated by [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) (emphasis added by myself).

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace **are not supported** for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.

I have successfully used GDI+ within an ASP.NET application several times, and have never faced any problems, but I guess it's just good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with GDI+ at least. A short answer: use .Graphics.SetClip() to set your desired shape and then draw you image. Everything outside the clipping region will be cut away.

Here's an article disussing a method that will bring smoother corners (and even softed edges if you like): http://danbystrom.se/2008/08/24/soft-edged-images-in-gdi/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to find yourself a library that can do such thing to an image.
I've found sth on CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/rounded_corners.aspx but I'm not sure if this is going to work with asp.net (that's basically a thing that you should google).

Then when you have a library you do your job with uploading a file and when it's uploaded you check the mime-type, try to open it and use the library.

Comment: Assuming what danbystrom wrote I suppose that the library from CP is also going to work, because it uses GDI.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned whether this is web or not, but have you considered rounding the images with css and/or javascript? Once you remove that image detail you can't get it back! What if the client wants a different clip shape later?