# Create image on the fly with Text and images in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing

Anybody have any sample in asp.net to create images on the fly? I have googled and found few articles but everything discuss about converting a Text into image. But I want to create an image which by joining few small thumbnails and text.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "on the fly" ?

Comment: I want to create the image when user click a submit button.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1790181/47093

Also note that GDI+ is not supported in ASP.NET

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this (Sorry don't know C#)

```
Public Function CreateImageFromThumbnails(ByVal lstImages As List(Of Image)) As Bitmap

    Dim width As Integer = 0
    Dim height As Integer = Integer.MinValue
    For Each img In lstImages
        If img.Height > height Then
            height = img.Height
        End If
        width += img.Width
    Next

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(width, height)
    Using fnt As New Font("Verdana", 14)
        Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            For Each img As Image In lstImages
                gfx.DrawImageUnscaled(img, x, 0)
                x += img.Width
            Next
            gfx.DrawString("Sample String", fnt, Brushes.White, 0, 0)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return bmp

End Function

Public Sub CreateImage()

    Dim lstImages As New List(Of Image)
    lstImages.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("thumbnail1.png"))
    lstImages.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("thumbnail2.png"))
    lstImages.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("thumbnail3.png"))
    lstImages.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("thumbnail4.png"))
    Using result As Bitmap = CreateImageFromThumbnails(lstImages)
        result.Save("c:\result.bmp")
    End Using

End Sub
```